# Игра змейка. Баги

Tags: python, python-3.x

Я хочу создать игру **"змейка"** без модуля **Pygame**, всё практически готово, но есть 2 критических бага:

1. Это баг движения, если быть конкретным, то во время поворота поворачивается всё тело. Сразу скажу, что передвижение происходит по средству телепортации части тела в впередистоящую (PS. сама змейка это массив, где расположены координаты каждого тела, пример: [[0,2],[0,3]])
2. Это баг рисовки, по тем или иным причинам справа от головы змейки появляется ещё одно тело.
   Прошу помощи, так как уже пытался делать всё, я переписывал код с нуля, переделывал функции и прочее. И хочу сказать перед тем, как вы увидите код: я только только начал изучать программирование и это мой первый вопрос на stack overflow, поэтому за говнокод и недостаток информации прошу прощенья.

Так же: код нужно запускать именно в терминале, в pycharm(овском) изначальном он не работает как следует.
Код:

```
import os, time, random, keyboard
class main_logic:
    snake = [[2, 2], [1, 2]]
    food = [5, 5]
    side = 2
    score = 0

    def move(self, side):
        snake = self.snake
        NewHeadX = snake[0][0]
        NewHeadY = snake[0][1]
        if side == 0:  # вверх
            NewHeadY -= 1
            self.side = 0
            print("Повернули наверх")
        elif side == 1:  # вниз
            NewHeadY += 1
            self.side = 1
            print("Повернули вниз")
        elif side == 2:  # вправо
            NewHeadX += 1
            self.side = 2
            print("Повернули вправо")
        elif side == 3:  # влево
            NewHeadX -= 1
            self.side = 3
            print("Повернули влево")
        if self.food[0] == NewHeadX and self.food[1] == NewHeadY:
            snake.append([0, 0])
            self.score += 1
            self.foodspawn(self)
        for i in range(len(snake)):
            if i == 0:
                pass
            elif i > 0:
                b = i - 1
                snake[i][0] = snake[b][0]
                snake[i][1] = snake[b][1]
        snake[0][0] = NewHeadX
        snake[0][1] = NewHeadY

        self.snake = snake
        return snake

    def foodspawn(self):
        y = random.randint(0, 9)
        x = random.randint(0, 9)
        food = [x, y]
        self.food = food
        return food


def printer():
    map_top = "┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐\n"
    map_bottom = "└───────────────────────────────────────────────────┘"
    symbols = ["△", "▽", "▷", "◁", "#", "⎔"]  # Вверх, вниз, вправо, влево
    print(map_top)
    for y in range(10):
        for x in range(10):
            if x == main_logic.snake[0][0] and y == main_logic.snake[0][1]:
                print(symbols[main_logic.side], end="")
            elif x == main_logic.food[0] and y == main_logic.food[1]:
                print(symbols[5], end="")
            else:
                printed1 = False
            for s in range(len(main_logic.snake)):
                if x == main_logic.snake[s][0] and y == main_logic.snake[s][1]:
                    print(symbols[4], end="")
            if printed1 == False:
                print(" ", end="")
            if x >= 9:
                print("")
    print(map_bottom)
    print("У вас", main_logic.score, "очков!")


sec1 = time.time()
first = False
while True:
    def get_time(time_need):
        if time_need == "ms":
            sec = time.time()
            msec = (sec * 1000) % 1000
            return msec
        elif time_need == "m":
            minute = time.localtime()
            return minute[4]


    if keyboard.is_pressed('W'):
        key = "W"
        first = True
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('S'):
        key = "S"
        first = True
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('D'):
        key = "D"
        first = True
    elif keyboard.is_pressed('A'):
        key = "A"
        first = True

    sec = time.time()
    if sec - sec1 >= 2:
        sec1 = sec
        os.system("cls")
        if first == False:
            snake = main_logic.move(main_logic, 2)
        elif key == "W":
            snake = main_logic.move(main_logic, 0)
        elif key == "S":
            snake = main_logic.move(main_logic, 1)
        elif key == "D":
            snake = main_logic.move(main_logic, 2)
        elif key == "A":
            snake = main_logic.move(main_logic, 3)
        printer()
```

Comment: я как-то уже помогал со змейкой кому-то, да и сам когда-то ее писал, суть в том чтобы не было конфузов, самое лучшее переносить хвост в новую голову, старая голова становится шеей, Ваш код посмотрю, пока только написал совет)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Cделал небольшой пример кроме класса логики, надеюсь будет полезен.

```
class Snake:
  def __init__(self, snake): 
      self.snake = snake

  def get_body(self):
      return self.snake

  def get_direction(self): 
    neck = self.snake[len(self.snake)-2]
    head = self.snake[len(self.snake)-1]    
    if (head[1] > neck[1]): return 'down'
    if (head[1] < neck[1]): return 'up'
    if (head[0] < neck[0]): return 'left'
    if (head[0] > neck[0]): return 'right'

  def move(self, dx, dy):
    tail = self.snake.pop(0)
    head = self.snake[len(self.snake)-1]
    new_head = [head[0] + dx, head[1] + dy];
    self.snake.append(new_head);

  def move_down(self):
    self.move(0, 1)  

  def move_up(self):
    self.move(0, -1)  

  def move_left(self):
    self.move(-1, 0)  

  def move_right(self):
    self.move(1, 0)  


class Dashboard:
  def __init__(self, height, width):
    self.width = width
    self.height = height
    self.symbols = {
      "up": "△",
      'down': "▽",
      'right':"▷",
      'left':"◁",
      'body':"#",
      'apple':"⎔"
    } 
  def draw_dash(self, snake):
    lines = [[ "_" for i in range(self.width) ] for j in range(self.height) ]
    snake_body = snake.get_body();  
    snake_length = len(snake_body);  
    for i, [x,y] in enumerate(snake_body):
      lines[y][x] = self.symbols['body'] if i < snake_length-1 else self.symbols[snake.get_direction()]
    res = [ ''.join(line) for line in lines]
    print('\n'.join(res))

snake = [[2, 2], [2, 3], [2, 4]]
sn = Snake(snake)
db = Dashboard(10, 10)
db.draw_dash(sn)
sn.move_right()
db.draw_dash(sn)
```

Comment: я делаю так, чтобы можно было инициализировать нормально, вообще все лучше делать через методы, на то это и ооп, к примеру до начала игры пользователь может выбрать сложность и это будет влиять на то как змея уже лежит на плоскости

Comment: Извиняюсь это машинально я не пишу на питоне давно в основном на JS

Comment: Я вижу, что Вы используете двухмерный массив, но это не имеет особого смысла. Да это упрощает работу при создании таблиц и прочего.. но не игр. При условии изменения в ней каждую секунду (а мне нужно менять его каждую секунду) система нагружается (а python и так долго работает) и сам по себе двухмерный массив устарел. Лучше было бы сделать так: у каждого элемента есть своё местоположение и 2 цикла проверяют на наличие змеи или яблока в клетке.

Comment: дело тут не в массиве, это просто пример как можно делать не думаю что двумерный массив устарел, при желании можно работать вообще с одномерным это не сложно пересчитать

Comment: можно долго выискивать что с моим кодом не так а можно взять из него то что поможет доделать игру без багов

Comment: Знал бы Вашу реакцию вообще бы не отсылал ответа

Comment: @Thetester Не забывайте, пожалуйста, что отвечающие на SO - не нанятые вами разработчики, которые для вас пишут код за зарплату, а добровольцы.  Если вы считаете, что в коде Daniil Loban нужно "исправить баги" - возьмите и исправьте. Если вы считаете, что "лучше было бы сделать так" - возьмите и сделайте. Если вам не нравится полученный ответ - это только ваши проблемы, остальные участники вам ничего не должны.

Comment: @Thetester соглашусь с комментарием выше. Код отвечающего Вам человека гораздо лучше того, в котором используются классы, определенные с маленькой буквы и между словами в названии которых проглядываются _.