# Механизм поворота змейки на Python Pygame

Tags: python, pygame

Я решил сделать змейку на pygame. Всё смог написать, кроме поворота. В голове выглядит у меня это так: запоминается координата головы в момент нажатия кнопки, далее голова уходит в другую сторону, а тело поочередно вставая на место головы в момент нажатия, тоже поворачивает. Но что-то никак не получается это реализовать.

```
import pygame
from pygame import key
import random
import time

def motion(screen):
    global snake_body,snake_head,case
    snake_head[0] += snake_head[2]
    snake_head[1] += snake_head[3]
    for n in range(len(snake_body)):
        snake_body[n][0] += snake_body[n][2]
        snake_body[n][1] += snake_body[n][3]
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'yellow', (snake_body[n][0],snake_body[n][1]), 10)
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'yellow', (snake_head[0],snake_head[1]), 10)
    food()
    eating(adding)


def food():
    global snake_body,snake_head,case
    nose = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,15])
    if nose == 1:
        x = random.randrange(44,458)
        y = random.randrange(44,458)
        if len(case) != 3:
            case.append([x, y])


def eating(thg):
    global snake_body,snake_head,case
    xl = snake_body[-1][0]
    yl = snake_body[-1][1]
    xf = snake_head[0]
    yf = snake_head[1]
    delete = []
    for i in range(len(case)):
        if xf > case[i][0] - 7 and xf < case[i][0] + 7 and yf > case[i][1] - 7 and yf < case[i][1] + 7:
            if thg == 'down':
                snake_body.append([xl,yl + 10,0,-1])
                delete.append(i)
            if thg == 'up':
                snake_body.append([xl,yl - 10,0,1])
                delete.append(i)
            if thg == 'left':
                snake_body.append([xl - 10,yl,1,0])
                delete.append(i)
            if thg == 'right':
                snake_body.append([xl + 10,yl,-1,0])
                delete.append(i)
    for i in delete:
        del case[i]


def lose(screen):
    global snake_body,snake_head,case
    case = []
    font = pygame.font.Font(None,50)
    textwon1 = font.render('YOU LOSED!',True,(100,255,100))
    screen.blit(textwon1,(155,220))
    textnewgame1 = font.render('NEW GAME',True,(100,255,100))
    screen.blit(textnewgame1,(165,270))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(100,255,100), (155,260,215,50),1)
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print(event.pos[0],event.pos[1])
        if 380 > event.pos[0] > 155 and 290 > event.pos[1] > 260:
            snake_head = [250,250,1,0]
            snake_body = [[240,250,1,0],[230,250,1,0]]
            adding = 'left'




if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    size = width,height = 500,500
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    running = True
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    snake_head = [250,250,1,0]
    snake_body = [[240,250,1,0],[230,250,1,0]]
    case = []
    adding = 'left'


    #задаем цикл, который выступает в качестве обработчика
    while running:
        #создаем эвент на закрытие программы
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP and adding != 'up':
                    adding = 'down'
                    snake_head[2] = 0
                    snake_head[3] = -1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and adding != 'down':
                    adding = 'up'
                    snake_head[2] = 0
                    snake_head[3] = 1
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and adding != 'right':
                    adding = 'left'
                    snake_head[2] = 1
                    snake_head[3] = 0
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT and adding != 'left':
                    adding = 'right'
                    snake_head[2] = -1
                    snake_head[3] = 0
            
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', (10,10,480,480),1)


        for n in case:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, 'yellow', (n[0],n[1]), 7)

        if snake_head[0] > 478 or snake_head[0] < 22 or snake_head[1] > 478 or snake_head[1] < 22:
            lose(screen)
        else:
            motion(screen)


        clock.tick(100)
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.fill('black')

pygame.quit()
```

Comment: А зачем вы храните голову отдельно? Храните только body. И считайте головой body[0]. Ну и "передвижение" змеи делается элементарно - с начала списка вставляется новый элемент (голова) с новыми координатами по направлению движения. а последний элемент списка (хвост) удаляется. И не надо ничего делать с остальными частями body. И хранить их "направление" тоже не надо.

Comment: я сделал по вашему совету, действительно получилось, спасибо

но он какой-то дерганный, как мне сделать его плавным?

Comment: сам когда-то ее писал, суть в том чтобы не было конфузов, самое лучшее переносить хвост в новую голову, старая голова становится шеей [пример в ответе](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1226242/%d0%98%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0-%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%b9%d0%ba%d0%b0-%d0%91%d0%b0%d0%b3%d0%b8/1226291#1226291)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Поигрался с вашим кодом. Вот, что у меня получилось.

```
import pygame
from pygame import key
import random
import time

config = {
    "head_size" : 10,
    "head_color": "blue",
    "body_space": 10,
    "body_size" : 8,
    "body_color": "yellow",
    "body_start_length": 2,
    "case_size" : 7,
    "case_color": "green",
    "case_max"  : 3
}

def motion(screen):
    global snake_add
    if snake_add: snake_add -= 1      # extending snake
    else        : snake_body.pop(0)   # delete tail
    snake_body.append(tuple(map(sum, zip(snake_body[-1], movement))))  # add head
    #for xy in snake_body[:-1:config["body_space"]]: # alt variant
    for xy in snake_body[::-1][config["body_space"]::config["body_space"]]:
        pygame.draw.circle(screen, config["body_color"], xy, config["body_size"])
    pygame.draw.circle(screen, config["head_color"], snake_body[-1], config["head_size"])
    food()
    eating()


def self_inersect():
    xh,yh = snake_body[-1] # head coords
    distance = (config["head_size"] + config["case_size"]) ** 2  # touch distance
    for x,y in snake_body[:-int((config["head_size"] + config["case_size"]+1)*1.5-2)]:
        if (xh - x)**2 + (yh - y)**2 < distance:
            return True
    return False


def food():
    if not case or len(case) < config["case_max"]:
        nose = random.choice([1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10,11,12,13,14,15,15]) if case else 1
        if nose == 1:
            x = random.randrange(44,458)
            y = random.randrange(44,458)
            case.append((x, y))


def eating():
    global snake_add
    xh,yh = snake_body[-1] # head coords
    distance = (config["head_size"] + config["case_size"]) ** 2  # touch distance
    for i,(x,y) in enumerate(case):
        if (xh - x)**2 + (yh - y)**2 < distance:
            snake_add += config["body_space"]
            case.pop(i)


def lose(screen):
    global case
    case = []
    font = pygame.font.Font(None,50)
    textwon1 = font.render('YOU LOSE!',True,(110,255,100))
    screen.blit(textwon1,(168,220))
    textnewgame1 = font.render('NEW GAME',True,(100,255,100))
    screen.blit(textnewgame1,(165,270))
    pygame.draw.rect(screen,(100,255,100), (155,260,215,50),1)
    if event.type == pygame.MOUSEBUTTONDOWN:
        print(event.pos[0],event.pos[1])
        if 380 > event.pos[0] > 155 and 290 > event.pos[1] > 260:
            new_game()


def new_game():
    global snake_body, case, movement, snake_add
    # snake head is the last element of list
    snake_body = [(250-i, 250) for i in range(config["body_start_length"]*config["body_space"]+1)][::-1]
    movement = (1, 0)    
    case = []
    snake_add = 0


if __name__ == '__main__':
    pygame.init()
    size = width,height = 500,500
    screen = pygame.display.set_mode(size)
    clock = pygame.time.Clock()
    new_game()

    #задаем цикл, который выступает в качестве обработчика
    running = True
    while running:
        #создаем эвент на закрытие программы
        for event in pygame.event.get():
            if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
                running = False
            
            if event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
                if event.key == pygame.K_UP and not movement[1]:
                    movement = (0, -1)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_DOWN and not movement[1]:
                    movement = (0, 1)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_RIGHT and not movement[0]:
                    movement = (1, 0)
                elif event.key == pygame.K_LEFT  and not movement[0]:
                    movement = (-1, 0)
            
        pygame.draw.rect(screen, 'white', (10,10,480,480),1)


        for xy in case:
            pygame.draw.circle(screen, config["case_color"], xy, config["case_size"])

        x, y = snake_body[-1]
        if 22 <= x <= 478 and 22 <= y <= 478 and not self_inersect():
            motion(screen)
        else:
            lose(screen)

        clock.tick(100)
        pygame.display.flip()
        screen.fill('black')

pygame.quit()
```